# Would knowing the exact weight that has been loaded on a commercial plane and it's distribution be useful?

Tags: stability, weight-and-balance, commercial-operations, weight

There's been a bit in the media about weighing passengers in order to get more accurate take off weights for commercial planes.  I'm guessing the delta between a heavy set of passengers and a light set might be 3000 kg.  If there was a cheap way of determining the weight that has been loaded onto a commercial jet would it be valuable out not, given this level of weight difference? I am after an actual cost. What is the cost of an airliner carrying the
additional fuel required by current rules if it assumed the overall mass estimate is 3000kg too high throughout its life? It won't be using that fuel but it will have to carry it.

Comment: "current estimations are enough" ???  Investigations need facts, or, better yet prevent the accident before it happens.  This question is not only about weight, but also distribution.  It does not seem to be a duplicate.

Comment: RE edit, are you asking about the accuracy of *fuel* loading? Because fuel loading is not related to the mentioned passenger-weighing. Please clarify further. If it is the cost of carrying extra fuel, then check this please: [How much fuel is burned to carry the trip fuel?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39513/14897)

Comment: A very important consideration would be adequate fuel reserve safety margin for headwinds, go arounds, unanticipated delays, etc. as compared with total weight of aircraft.  A study of frequency of fuel starvation incidents with current margins would also be in order.

Comment: Ymb1 - I have edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

YES.

The obvious solution is to roll the plane over a scale.  Useful CG data can also be obtained by weighing the front wheel and comparing its torque to known values.  A light front wheel means an aft CG.  This could be corrected by moving fuel BEFORE the plane is airborne, as well as while in flight.

Of course, moving passengers and cargo are an option too.

For example the plane weighs in at 2200 lbs total on the ramp ready to go.  The nose wheel weight is 200 lbs.  The distance between the main and nose wheels is 11 feet.  The aft CG limit is 0.75 feet forward of the mains.

CG is calculated as follows:  200 lbs/2200 lbs = 1/11. 
          CG is 1/11 * 11 feet = 1.00 feet forward of mains. 
          CG is with in limits.

And how accurate weighing the nose wheel can be (due to long torque arm):

Nose wheel weight 100 lbs.  Total weight 2200 lbs.
        100 lbs/2200 lbs = 1/22.
         CG is 1/22 * 11 feet = 0.500 feet forward of mains.
         CG is NOT in limits.

Comment: Technically nothing incorrect here, but the question had to do with larger commercial jets.  2200 lbs is around the weight of a Cessna 172, and yes, small planes are very sensitive to CG as well as overloading.  I agree with Ymb1's answer on the duplicate question linked above.

Comment: @Michael Hall I drive a 40 ton tractor trailer.  We go over scales. As a matter of fact, this approach is "scalable" through a wide range of types.  The benefit is being able to do gross weight and CG with some simple algebra.

Comment: And I promise I will not attempt to answer authoritatively on any questions pertaining to 40 ton tractor trailers.

Comment: I agree with you, but if it is truly a good idea then why aren't airlines doing it?  Ultimately it is a business decision based on cost vs benefit.  Driving over a set of scales costs precious time and fuel to verify with just a bit more accuracy what you already know.  Also, if it was important enough to safety then it would likely be mandated by the FAA.  It isn't like nobody has thought of it before...

Comment: @Michael Hall OK, as a comment (answers should be authoritative), 3 reasons.  Aircraft are being designed to tighter aerodynamic specs, yet a huge amount of variables such as runway length, weather, traffic patterns, payload, and CG remain.  As planes are tweaked to perfection, their tolerance to these variables may be less.  Airports designed in the last century also need to keep pace, and gov't regulations for Passenger Aircraft could be such that over competition by Majors for the most "efficient" planes will not lead to danger.  Weighing and fuel transfer preflight could make it safer.

Comment: Then my advice is to invest in a system of scales and make your case to industry.  Again, I am confident that this has been considered and decided against by professionals with a lot more specific knowledge on the subject than either of us.

Comment: For cargo aircraf,t going over a scales and thus having the weight on the individual landing gears is not going to allow you to check the linear limits, the fwd and aft cumulative limits (sometimes referred to as the monocoque limits), and the individual position limits. It also would not allow you to make maximal use of asymmetric limits position limits for wide body aircraft.

Comment: @Terry. Look at a triple beam balance. Just weighing the nose wheel would tell you a lot.  Most critical is CG position.  For cargo aircraft it has also been proposed to slide the cargo bay floor over a simple roller set at optimal CG until it tips.  Getting CG right can help if the designer wants a smaller tail.  But weighing the individual pallets as they go on and doing a proper load sheet certainly will work too!  Weighing the nose wheel only double checks it before flying.

Comment: And BTW, if we bothered to build a scale house (@Radu pointed out wind is a factor), we might get a little de icing done too.